# Delete an item(Object) from an array using ng-if

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to remove item using ng-if and ng-else-if.
"ng-if="navItem.gbn.indexOf('12345') !== -1" is true then array item only show contains('12345') items.
but the item still remain in array so I think ng-else-if is not working.
I don't know how to delete it.

I have the following Angular code:

```
    <div ng-controller="PIDAEController"> 
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:30px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 tubmbimg" ng-repeat="navItem in navItems | Fpage: curPage * pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-if="navItem.gbn.indexOf('12345') !== -1">
                        <a class="thumbnail border" href="#/item/{{navItem.site}}">
                            <div class="b-marjin">
                                <span align="center" class="label label-primary full-width" >{{ navItem.gbn }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <img style="border: 1px solid black;" class="img-responsive full-width" src="{{navItem.pimg}}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div align="center" class="under-block">
                                <span title="{{ navItem.pname }}" align="center">{{ navItem.pname2}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div ng-else-if="navItems.splice(navItem, 1)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
angular.forEach(item, function (value, key) {
    var keepGoing = true;
    if(keepGoing) {
        if(value.gbn.indexOf("11600") != -1) {
            $scope.initialized = true;
            $scope.navItems = item;
            $scope.curPage=0;
            $scope.pageSize=20;
            $scope.numberOfPage = Math.ceil(item.length / $scope.pageSize);
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        else {
            $scope.navItems.splice(key, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-else-if does NOT EXIST. its neither angular or angularJS.

In the line

```
<div ng-else-if="navItems.splice(navItem, 1)"></div>
```

splice requires navItem to be an index/int, not an object.

As an alternative to ng-else-if you can simply do:

```
ng-if="navItem.gbn.indexOf('12345') == -1
```

Also, splice would return the removed array item when found, not sure if "ng-if" handles that as being TRUE.

Comment: Great Answer, So I am trying to in js
I edit my Question.
splice function still not working in js code

Comment: I think the problem here is that since your navItems is an object containing objects, and not an array, 'key' is a string in your forEach loop, and cannot be used with splice. At least it looks like since your looking for the string key "11600" in navItems, and not array index number 11600. In order to get the index NUMBER from an object key, you can do: $scope.navItems.splice(Object.keys($scope.navItems).indexOf(key), 1);